# Override Default Route Based on Condition on Incoming Shipment (Receipts) while Confirming the Purchase Order Odoo 13

Tags: odoo, odoo-13

What im trying to achieve is while confirming a purchase order based on a condition in then order, needs to replace the default route with a custom route.
Please share your valuable references or suggetions

Answer (score 1):

You need to inherit the _prepare_stock_moves function of purchase.order.line and check for the condition if true then update the routes with the custom route

```
 class PurchaseOrderLine(models.Model):
     _inherit = 'purchase.order.line'

     def _prepare_stock_moves(self,picking):
         res = super(PurchaseOrderLine,self)._prepare_stock_moves(picking)
         if self.order_id.condition:
             res['route_ids'] = [(6,0,custom_route.ids)]
         return res
```

Comment: Thanks for the Response @Eslan.

I dont know why but inherited function is not running, i've checked all the possible scenarios,
Like Importing the file (from odoo.addons.purchase_stock.models.purchase import PurchaseOrderLine as HcPurchaseOrderLine)
even checked the init file.
i dont know why it is not triggering, please let know

Comment: @Eslan Im guessing im missing something here

Comment: [_prepare_stock_moves](https://github.com/odoo/odoo/blob/13.0/addons/purchase_stock/models/purchase.py#L387) will return a list of values, you check how Odoo uses it when it [creates or update a picking](https://github.com/odoo/odoo/blob/13.0/addons/purchase_stock/models/purchase.py#L361). The function prepares the stock moves data for one order line. It returns a list of dictionaries ready to be used in stock.move's `create()`

Comment: Actually At the warehouse for All the other incoming shipments, I had configured the route as Receiving in 2 steps (input + stock), 
And by the help of you guys i was able to update the res['route ids'] on the _prepare_stock_moves. (for example Route i configured is Vendor Location-A to WH/Stock-B)

But The transfer is still being created with the same settings as the warehouse even though the res['route ids'] on the _prepare stock moves have been altered. 

 @Kenly

Comment: @Raihan Please show what you have tried. Updating the `res` list like above will raise the following error: `TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not str`